# Async background downloading using iOS standard classes etc

Tags: ios, nsurlconnection, nsoperationqueue

I want to download several pages over https, using NSURLConnection and NSOperationQueue(?). I don't want to use ASIHTTPRequest or similar since I don't want my code to depend on them updating their code (if needed) when Apple update the iOS. I want to use plain Apple stuff.

About 100 pages will be downloaded, they have a url to a image that also should be downloaded. This link is not known before downloading the previous page. I believe 5 or maybe some more concurrent downloads should run in the same time.

How do I keep track of everything and the progress of my downloads and in the same time accomplish to have a responsive user interface?

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use NSURLConnection and NSOperationQueue as you already wrote.
NSURLConnection has a class function

```
+ (void)sendAsynchronousRequest:(NSURLRequest *)request queue:(NSOperationQueue *)queue completionHandler:(void (^)(NSURLResponse*, NSData*, NSError*))handler
```

There you can define which NSOperationQueue it should belong to and you can define a completion handler. The handler is a block which will be performed when the NSURLConnection is finished. In the block you are able to access the NSURLResponse.
Since the whole thing is asynchronous the user interface you be accessible.

One great advantage here is that the blocks can be performed on different cpu cores.